# read the data in two files from the command line and substract from each other the data

Tags: python

I need to substract from each other the data in two files but I get this error:NameError: name 'first1' is not defined. Could you please tell me how to fix this error? The command I use to run the code is here: python script.py input1.txt input2.txt > output.txt

```
import numpy
from numpy import *
import scipy
from pylab import *
import sys

def main(argv):
    t = open(sys.argv[1])
    first1 = t.readline()

    tt = open(argv[2])
    second2 = tt.readline()
    return [first1], [second2]

def result(first1, second2):

    first = np.array(first1, dtype = np.float64)
    second = np.array(second2, dtype = np.float64)

    #subtract
    sub = (first - second)

    return [sub]

result(first1, second2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

**input1.txt:**

```
2.5
2.8
3.9
4.2
5.8
```

**input2.txt:**

```
0.8
2.5
3.2
5.8
6.3
```

Comment: So what is that lonely `result(first1, second2)` between `result` and `main` supposed to do and how do you expect it to know what `first1` and `second2` are?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to do exactly but there are so many things wrong in your code. Here is a working version:

```
import sys

def main(argv):
    t = open(argv[1])
    first1 = list(map(float, t.read().split('\n')))

    tt = open(argv[2])
    second2 = list(map(float, tt.read().split('\n')))
    print(*result(first1, second2), sep = "\n")

def result(first1, second2):
    return [round(first1[i] - second2[i], 3) for i in range(len(first1))]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv)
```